# Android Studio Error: build scan was not published

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

I am building basic app in Kotlin. I have added a listview and it was working fine. but when I try to implement google map then I got following error in android studio 3.1.

```
The build scan was not published due to a configuration problem.
    
   The Gradle Cloud Services license agreement has not been agreed to.
    
   To agree to the license, include the following in your root project's configuration:
    buildScan { licenseAgreementUrl = 'https://gradle.com/terms-of-service'; licenseAgree = 'yes' }
    
   For more information, please see https://gradle.com/scans/help/plugin-license.
    
   Alternatively, if you are using Gradle Enterprise, specify the server location.
    For more information, please see https://gradle.com/scans/help/plugin-enterprise-config.
    
   9:27:52 PM: Task execution finished 'signingReport'.
```

I have tried every available solution on the net like:

```
buildScan {
  licenseAgreementUrl = "https://gradle.com/terms-of-service"
  licenseAgree = "yes"
}
```

I have also added the plugin: `apply plugin: com.gradle.build-scan`
but no luck.

Comment: There are two separate "build.gradle" files. This one is referring to the project level build.gradle, rather than your module app/build.gradle. make sure you've added it to the correct one.

Comment: yes, i have tried in  both files but same error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to accept Gradle ToS for \`build --scan\` automatically and still manage to run build without a scan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52636622/how-to-accept-gradle-tos-for-build-scan-automatically-and-still-manage-to-ru)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the following code from build.gradle file and Sync your Gradle again. Everything will be resolved.

```
apply plugin: 'com.gradle.build-scan'

buildScan {
    licenseAgreementUrl = 'https://gradle.com/terms-of-service'
    licenseAgree = 'yes'
}
```

Comment: yes, you are right. I have fixed the issue but your answer is 100%  correct. thanks for your reply.

Comment: My code didn't contain any of these lines. How can I resolve it now?

Comment: If you just upvoted @Stuti Kasliwal then go and use https://stackoverflow.com/a/63111087/1866373 :)

Answer (score 5):

[The accepted answer in this other question works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52642692/3423932). You have to test the existence of `buildScan` task.

```
if (hasProperty('buildScan')) {
    buildScan {
        termsOfServiceUrl = 'https://gradle.com/terms-of-service'
        termsOfServiceAgree = 'yes'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

build scan plugin was deprecated, use gradle enterprise instead.

In your `settings.gradle.kts` file:

```
plugins {
  id("com.gradle.enterprise") version("3.12.2")
}

gradleEnterprise {
  buildScan {
    termsOfServiceUrl = "https://gradle.com/terms-of-service"
    termsOfServiceAgree = "yes"
  }
}
```