# How to accept Gradle ToS for `build --scan` automatically and still manage to run build without a scan?

Tags: gradle, build-error

> I am using Gradle 4.6 which allows me to run [build scans](https://scans.gradle.com/) using
>   the `--scan` option without having to explicitly apply or download
>   extra plugins which is great. However this forces me to add the
>   `buildScan` Terms of Service acceptance in my build.gradle file.

like this:

```
buildScan {
    termsOfServiceUrl = 'https://gradle.com/terms-of-service'
    termsOfServiceAgree = 'yes'
}
```

> When I subsequently run `gradle build` without the `--scan` option I
>   get the following error message:
>
> ```
> > Could not find method buildScan() for arguments…
> ```
>
> I don’t want to have to modify the build.gradle file every time I
>   want/dont want a scan. I don’t want to apply the plugin explicitly
>   (firewall issues) and I don’t get the chance to accept the of Terms of
>   Service on the command line which I have also seen documented.
>
> Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

This question is formatted like a quote because it was already asked on [Gradle Forums](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/running-the-scan-option-with-gradle-4-6-without-changing-my-build-gradle/26238). But it's left without answer. I'm using Gradle 4.10.2 and the problem is still actual. I decided to draw more attention to this problem here.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Just test the existence of `buildScan`

```
if (hasProperty('buildScan')) {
    buildScan {
        termsOfServiceUrl = 'https://gradle.com/terms-of-service'
        termsOfServiceAgree = 'yes'
    }
}
```

The same can be done in a kotlin build file like this - ([with thanks to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56634703/197141)):

```
if (hasProperty("buildScan")) {
    extensions.findByName("buildScan")?.withGroovyBuilder {
        setProperty("termsOfServiceUrl", "https://gradle.com/terms-of-service")
        setProperty("termsOfServiceAgree", "yes")
    }
}
```

Please see [Connecting to scans.gradle.com](https://gradle.com/help/plugin-terms-of-service) documentation for more detail.

Comment: If anyone knows how to translate this to Kotlin DSL please answer at https://stackoverflow.com/q/55725574/1127485, thanks in advance.

Comment: What section is this supposed to go within build.gradle (app)?

Comment: @TaslimOseni put it in the top level build.gradle (not the one with dependencies). Put it just above `buildscript`

Comment: If you don’t have a top-level `build.gradle` yet, you should create it. Oh, and be sure [not to commit agreement to the terms of service into a project that may be built by others](https://docs.gradle.com/enterprise/gradle-plugin/#connecting_to_scans_gradle_com).

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a good or proper solution, but here's one workaround: use a `try`/`catch` to swallow the error, something like:

```
try {
    buildScan {
        termsOfServiceUrl = 'https://gradle.com/terms-of-service'
        termsOfServiceAgree = 'yes'
    }
} catch (MissingMethodException e){
   // This isn't the exception you're looking for
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe "yes" as the answer using the `echo` command

For example,

```
echo "yes" | ./gradlew build --scan
```