# How to conditionally accept Gradle build scan plugin terms of service in Kotlin DSL?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-dsl

This basically extends [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52636622/1127485) to Kotlin DSL instead of Groovy DSL:

How does the [Groovy DSL solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52642692/1127485) of

```
if (hasProperty('buildScan')) {
    buildScan {
        termsOfServiceUrl = 'https://gradle.com/terms-of-service'
        termsOfServiceAgree = 'yes'
    }
}
```

translate to Kotlin DSL?

The problem I'm running is that the "buildScan" extension or the `com.gradle.scan.plugin.BuildScanExtension` class cannot statically be used as they are either present or not present depending on whether the `--scan` command line argument was provided to Gradle or not.

I've tried

```
if (hasProperty("buildScan")) {
    extensions.configure("buildScan") {
        termsOfServiceUrl = "https://gradle.com/terms-of-service"
        termsOfServiceAgree = "yes"
    }
}
```

but as expected `termsOfServiceUrl` and `termsOfServiceAgree` do not resolve, however I'm clueless what syntax to use here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Gradle Kotlin DSL provides a `withGroovyBuilder {}` utility extension that attaches the Groovy metaprogramming semantics to any object. See the [official documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#the_kotlin_dsl_groovy_builder).

```
extensions.findByName("buildScan")?.withGroovyBuilder {
  setProperty("termsOfServiceUrl", "https://gradle.com/terms-of-service")
  setProperty("termsOfServiceAgree", "yes")
}
```

This ends up doing reflection, just like Groovy, but it keeps the script a bit more tidy.

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly nice, but using reflection it works:

```
if (hasProperty("buildScan")) {
    extensions.configure("buildScan") {
        val setTermsOfServiceUrl = javaClass.getMethod("setTermsOfServiceUrl", String::class.java)
        setTermsOfServiceUrl.invoke(this, "https://gradle.com/terms-of-service")

        val setTermsOfServiceAgree = javaClass.getMethod("setTermsOfServiceAgree", String::class.java)
        setTermsOfServiceAgree.invoke(this, "yes")
    }
}
```